# Concatenating a DWORD and a LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, string

I have a legacy Windows application that logs an error. It would be nice to find what kind of error is thrown, but after finding the source code for the project I realize this is C++ and I have virtually no experience with C++.

The error code is a `DWORD`, and the input to the log function takes a `LPCTSTR`.

The code is as follows right now:

```
DWORD dwError;
dwError = SomeFunction();

if (dwError)
{
    Log(_T("Something failed"));
}
```

So I would like to have the value of `dwError` put into the log message. Coming from a C# background I tried `Log(_T("Something failed (" + dwError + ")"));` but that obviously didn't work.

I have also tried reading up on concatenating `LPCTSTR` values. I did find some hits but they seem very complicated and I don't know how to knead them into something for this legacy code.

How can I get `dwError` to be a part of the log message, preferably in HEX notation.

Comment: Such message can be necessary at many locations in your program. You shoudl consider to extend the Log function to accept varargs: `Log(PTCHAR szMesage, ...);` Then you implement this once with `vstprintf` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/). You can use the function in the current case as `Log(_T("Something failed: %u"), dwError);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is tagged C++, but the code is and question is written in a C style - the solutions in each vary;

For C++, make use of `std::basic_string`;

```
DWORD dwError;
dwError = SomeFunction();

if (dwError)
{
    std::basic_string<TCHAR> msg(_T("Something failed: "));
    msg += std::to_string(dwError);
    Log(msg.c_str());
}
```

A more C style would be;

```
DWORD dwError;
dwError = SomeFunction();

if (dwError)
{
    TCHAR buffer[1024] = {};
    _stprintf(buffer, _T("Something failed: %u"), dwError);
    Log(buffer);
}
```

The documentation for the [`sprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx) links to the [format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx), and for HEX, it would be [`%X`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx).

```
_stprintf(buffer, _T("Something failed: %X"), dwError);
```